# Mailing List Archive

Tags: mailing-list

We have as number of discussion lists that are locked away within mailman.  I want to develop an archive of the lists, including the possibility of extending the archive with new contributions, visualisations, etc.  Has anyone any suggestions for possible software?

Answer (score 2):

MarkMail/MarkLogic is good:

MarkMail Info:
http://www.marklogic.com/product/mmoverview.html

MarkLogic Info:
http://www.marklogic.com/product/marklogic-server.html

MarkLogic Download:
http://developer.marklogic.com/download/default.xqy

Answer (score 0):

...and MarkMail itself is here: http://markmail.org/